# Iterate a JSON array with an array field with Q promises nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I am new with the Q promises.
I have a JSON with this structure like input:

```
[{"code": x,
  "status": y,
  "array": [
    {  "value1": k   },
    {  "value2": z   }
  },{...}
...]
```

Now I have to save it in two different collections in MongoDB with an ObjectId reference; so I want something like that:

```
C1: {"_id": 1,"code": x, "status": y, "array": [2,3]}
C2: {"_id": 2,"value1": k},{"_id":3, "value2": z}
```

I try to iterate with two array map, like this:

```
Q.all(codes.map(function(currCode) {
       return this.saveNewCode(currCode)
         .then(function(code) {
            return Q.all(currCode.array.map(function(currElem) {
                return this.saveNewElem(currElem)
                   .then(function(elem) {
                       return this.addElemToCode(elem.id,code.id)
                   })
            }))
         })
}))
```

In this way the return is a map [[]], and I would like to return a response like the initial json.

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to explain. Could you provide more details and an example of how you wrote your js code?

Comment: I wasn't clear. I edit now.